# Scraping data by a specific element name - PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS to pull out some data from the twitter page. Here is a sample content that I'm trying to scrape:

```
<span class="ProfileTweet-action--reply u-hiddenVisually">
  <span class="ProfileTweet-actionCount"  data-tweet-stat-count="541">
    <span class="ProfileTweet-actionCountForAria" data-aria-label-part>541 replies .</span>
  </span>
</span>
```

This is my code for getting the reply count:

```
var replyCount = page.evaluate(function(){
 return document.getElementsByClassName("ProfileTweet-action--reply");
});
for (var i = 0; i < replyCount.length; i++) {
    var replyInt = replyCount[i].innerText;
    console.log(replyInt);
}
```

Output is `541 replies`

Is there a way to scrape the value just for `data-tweet-stat-count` so I can get "541"?

There are also other elements with the same name `data-tweet-stat-count` in that page. Can anyone lead me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var replyCount = page.evaluate(function(){
    return document.querySelector('span.ProfileTweet-action--reply span.ProfileTweet-actionCount').getAttribute('data-tweet-stat-count');
});
```